# Controlling Lights / Sounds of Nest Protect

Tags: led, nest-api

I want to find out if there is a programmatic way to control the lights of the nest protect.  For example, what if I want the nest protect to turn green? 
Also, is there a way to have the nest protect speak programmatically?

Comment: Why would this get down-voted. It's a perfectly reasonable question and it ought to be possible. Anyone curious ought to be able to ask if it is or be told why it isn't. Speaking programmatically would be a highly beneficial additional feature as would being able to control the "night light" white LED.

Answer (score 1):

Nest Protect is a safety product and the light colors have very [specific meanings](http://support.nest.com/article/What-do-the-lights-mean-on-Nest-Protect). As such the [API for the Protect](https://developer.nest.com/documentation/api-reference) is read only.